# Rotate object around arbitrary axis in Three.js,just like the moon around the Earth.

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotatetransform

I have tried many solutions of the question,but the object
still around his own axis without any translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add the object as the child of another object, and rotate that object instead...

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var w = 300;
var h = 200;
renderer.setSize( w,h );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
 45,  // Field of view
 w/h, // Aspect ratio
 0.1,  // Near
 10000  // Far
);
camera.position.set( 15, 10, 15 );
camera.lookAt( scene.position );
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0x808080 );
light.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
scene.add( light );
var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101010 );
light1.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
scene.add( light1 );
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x808080 );
light2.position.set( -20, 20, -20 );
scene.add( light2 );
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x808080 );
light3.position.set( -20, -20, -20 );
scene.add( light3 );
var mkBody=(rad,color)=>{   
var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(rad,16,16);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: color } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom, material );
return mesh;
}
var sun = mkBody(2,0xffee00)
scene.add( sun )
sun.material.emissive.set(0x808000)
var b1 = mkBody(0.7,0x80ffff)
b1.position.set(6,0,0)
sun.add( b1 )
var b2 = mkBody(0.2,0xeeeeee)
b2.position.set(1.1,0,0)
b1.add( b2 )
sun.onBeforeRender = function(){
    this.rotation.y+=0.01
}
b1.onBeforeRender = function(){
    this.rotation.y+=0.1
}
renderer.setClearColor( 0x404040, 1);

(function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Another option is to transform the geometry itself...

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var w = 300;
var h = 200;
renderer.setSize( w,h );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
 45,  // Field of view
 w/h, // Aspect ratio
 0.1,  // Near
 10000  // Far
);
camera.position.set( 15, 10, 15 );
camera.lookAt( scene.position );
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0x808080 );
light.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
scene.add( light );
var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101010 );
light1.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
scene.add( light1 );
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x808080 );
light2.position.set( -20, 20, -20 );
scene.add( light2 );
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x808080 );
light3.position.set( -20, -20, -20 );
scene.add( light3 );
var mkBody=(rad,color)=>{   
    var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(rad,16,16);
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: color } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom, material );
    return mesh;
}
var sun = mkBody(2,0xffee00)
scene.add( sun )
sun.material.emissive.set(0x808000)
var b1 = mkBody(0.7,0x80ffff)
b1.position.set(6,0,0)
sun.add( b1 )
b1.updateMatrixWorld();
b1.geometry.applyMatrix(b1.matrixWorld); //Transform the actual geometry...
scene.add(b1); //Now reparent it to the scene
b1.position.set(0,0,0); //And reset its position...

sun.onBeforeRender = function(){
    this.rotation.y+=0.01
}
b1.onBeforeRender = function(){
    this.rotation.y+=0.1
}
renderer.setClearColor( 0x404040, 1);

(function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,your answer is absolutely right,but,I want the object's parent is the scene instead of the others.

Comment: Then you'll have to compute the rotated position yourself and set it every frame..

But I bet you don't really need the parent to be the scene.. why do you think you need that?

Comment: I added a second snippet that transforms the geometry to take the offset into account. Now the sun and planet are both children of the scene...

Comment: Thanks a lot!perfect solution!

Comment: I'm sorry my reputation is too low,so I can't do the operation.sorry:-(